# How can I add a retry function for a task in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have a dag with multiple tasks. For one of the tasks, I want to retry it 5 times in case of failure in airflow. But that is not running for 5 times. Here is my code.

```
def build_task(self, dag):
    return PythonOperator(
        task_id='setup',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=lambda **kwargs: self._setup(Settings(**kwargs)),
        retries=5,
        retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=5),
        dag=dag)
```

Not understanding what went wrong!

Comment: Are you sure the task is failing? What states does it go through?

Comment: Yeah.. I am getting the FileNotFoundError. I intentionally made a mistake in my code to check if my retries really works

Comment: Basic Python exceptions don't set failed state for an Airflow task. To mark a task failed, you should explicitly raise AirflowException. Then it will go through the retry cycle.

Comment: Please post more of the relevent code. What function call to build task and what do you do with the output